# Python: Why is this for loop exiting after the first iteration?

Tags: python, for-loop, logic

**What I am trying to do:** I am importing from a csv and trying to iterate through the data to check for matches.

**What I have tried:**
I am trying a nested for loop, to iterate though the larger list, and check each for each item in the smaller list.

FYI "Pesticide Name" is the header of the column in the d_reader file, therefore it is the Key name.

```
agqfile=open("GCLC-USA-1.csv")
csv_a=csv.reader(agqfile)

d_reader=csv.DictReader(open("Pesticide_output.csv"))

 for row in d_reader:
#     print (row['Pesticide Name'])
    for chem in csv_a:
        print(chem[0],row['Pesticide Name'])
        if chem[0] in row['Pesticide Name']:
             print(chem[0],"found in ",row['Pesticide Name'])
 #     print(row['Pesticide Name'])
```

**What I expect:** 
The outer loop should not exit until it is completed, but it is exiting after the first iteration. 
However, if I put a print statement before the second (nested) for loop, it prints every iteration.

I do not understand this behaviour! Please can you help me by explaining it?

I was trying to keep this question as brief as possible, but **if you need more info, such as a sample of the data, or print out of datatypes, then I can provide this.**

Answer (score 2):

The inner loop exhausts the file-object `csv_a` in the first outer iteration, therefore the other outer rows never enter the inner loop.
You have to store the contents in a list:

```
agqfile=open("GCLC-USA-1.csv")
csv_a = list(csv.reader(agqfile))

d_reader=csv.DictReader(open("Pesticide_output.csv"))

for row in d_reader:
#     print (row['Pesticide Name'])
    for chem in csv_a:
        print(chem[0],row['Pesticide Name'])
        if chem[0] in row['Pesticide Name']:
             print(chem[0],"found in ",row['Pesticide Name'])
 #     print(row['Pesticide Name'])
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Actually, although your answer helped, I still don't understand the logic here, @Daniel. Even if the inner for loop exhausts the shorter object, should it not then just go on to the next iteration of the outer loop? 
Clearly I am misunderstanding something.

Comment: @Jimmy9zz: You gave the answer yourself: "However, if I put a print statement before the second (nested) for loop, it prints every iteration." So the outer loop finishes.